# How to solve a non-convex with equality constraint optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex, non-convex

I have a non-convex optimization problem with equality constraint, I can derive the KKT conditions, but it seems just one of the KKT conditions is valid. Could you please give some advice on how to determine the optimum value and get the solution?